# Google Keyboard takes a few seconds to enable autocorrect after the latest update. How do I fix this?

Tags: gboard

In the latest version of Google Keyboard (6.6.22) I've noticed that for some reason it takes 5-10 seconds for autocorrect to start working after the keyboard is loaded. I've disabled multi language typing but it didn't help.

Is there a setting I can change to make the keyboard load test dictionary fast again? Or perhaps it's a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by clearing the cache of Google Keyboard.